# How would I change cluster_name for an existing Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I would like to know how to change or modify the cluster name for the existing Cassandra cluster. I followed to update the cluster name using the below query but it failed while trying to alter the system table.

```
[cqlsh 6.8.0 | DSE 6.8.25 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | DSE protocol v2]

cqlsh> UPDATE system.local SET cluster_name = 'DummyCluster' where key='local';
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Modification is not supported by table system_views.local_node"
```

Answer (score 1):

@CassandraNovice, there is no official tools to get this done today. This is a risky operation. Instead, I would recommend you build the destination/target cluster and move data from source to this new cluster via tools such as [**DSBulk Loader**](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkAbout.html), [**Zero Downtime Migrations**](https://www.datastax.com/press-release/datastax-unveils-zero-downtime-cloud-migration-tool-move-workloads-apache-cassandra), etc.,

Answer (score 1):

Changing the name of an existing cluster is NOT a supported operation in Cassandra. This is the reason the procedure is not provided in any official documentation.

Cassandra experts are aware that there is a hack available to be able to rename an existing cluster but being experts, they are aware of the consequences of doing so.

For everyone else coming across this post in the future, do NOT try any instructions or procedures you find on the internet that allegedly allows you to rename your cluster. We don't recommend it so it's not supported. Cheers!